# aspnet_regiis is not able to find a custom app setting group

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, data-protection

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application. and I have defined a custom section group named `"customAppSettingsGroup"` inside my web.config:-

```
<configuration>
        <configSections>
            <sectionGroup name="customAppSettingsGroup">
                <section name="customAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            </sectionGroup>
            <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />


        </configSections>
        <customAppSettingsGroup>
            <customAppSettings>
          <add key="KeyOne" value="*****"/>

            </customAppSettings>
        </customAppSettingsGroup>
......
......
</configuration>
```

now i want to encrypt the  section mainly to encrypt the KeyOne value. so i wrote the following command :-

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pe "customAppSett
ingsGroup" -app "/Scanning" -prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"
```

but i got the following error :-

```
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.18408
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Encrypting configuration section...
The configuration section 'customAppSettingsGroup' was not found.
Failed!
```

so i am not sure why the commnad can not find the associated section ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects of your question.

1. You cannot encrypt sectionGroups. You can only encrypt sections. So your command line would need to change from `customAppSettingsGroup` to `customAppSettingsGroup/customAppSettings`.
2. The regiis command has to bind to your DLL the `customAppSettings` is defined in. There are two ways to solve this - either comment out the `sectionGroup` block in the `configSections` part of your web.config, or copy the DLL containing that definition into the folder that has aspnet_regiis.exe.